# Fade out image but not text on UILabel for iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, uilabel

I have a label I have added a background to like this:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some image"]];
```

The user will enter text into the label and when finished, I would like to have the background image fade away but have the text remain.  I've tried `UIView` Animations but `UIImage` does not inherit from `UIView` so that method has not worked and I am a bit stuck.  Either I need to add a background image to my label differently or animate in a different way to get the fade out.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a UIView where you add both another UIView with your background, and a UILabel on top, like so?

> UIView
>
> - UIView
> - UILabel (with [UIColor clearColor] as backgroundColor)

Then you can fade out the second UIView, and the UILabel will remain visible.as backgroundColor)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I ended up using a UIImageView on the label and fading that out.